# PHP - strtotime() return 1970

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

The following code snippet:

```
echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime("01.01.2000-11:12:32"));
```

returns me:

> 01.01.1970-01:00:00

What's the right way to convert "01.01.2000-11:12:32" to time/date object, for comparing it with the current timestamp?

e.g.

```
if (date("d.m.Y-H:i:s") > date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime("01.01.2000-11:12:32"))) {
    echo "future";
} else {
    echo "past";
}
```

Comment: Try changing the dots to slashes.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so.. dots are permitted?

Comment: Well, they are.. But this is due to localisation. Not in the left part, but on the right part.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you mean.. date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime("01/01/2000-11:12:32"))?

Comment: Man, look at my detailed answer. Reload the page.

Comment: Saw it.. will be accepted in a few mins. Working great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to localisation. Try giving a different format, as the format matters a lot:

```
echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime("01/01/2000 11:12:32"));
echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime("01-01-2000 11:12:32"));
```

1. You should not have `.` for date and month separator.
2. You cannot separate date and time using `-`.

If you are getting the input from another source, try using `str_replace`:

```
echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace(array(".", "-"), array("/", " "), "01.01.2000-11:12:32")));
```

**Output: http://ideone.com/d19ATK**

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `.` with `-`:

`echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', "01.01.2000 11:12:32")));`

Also remove `-` between the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y-H:i:s', '01.01.2000-11:12:32');
$now = new DateTime();

if ($now > $date) {
    echo "future";
} else {
    echo "past";
}
```